# Why am I unable to nest SUBSTITUTE in an IF statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am unable to figure out what is wrong with this formula:

```
=IF((SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1",3)<Sheet2!$B$6))
```

the `(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1",3)` essentially returns the value of the current column letter e.g. 'B'. The 3 at the end returns the row number. So altogether B3.

This is a date which is a short date type. It is then compared to another date, which is also short date type.

This formula doesn't work. When changing the formula to:

```
=IF((SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1",3)<Sheet2!$B$6),true,false)
```

it returns false regardless of whether the if condition is met or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is interesting that you substitute the string "1" by the number 3. I would goess that the nesting of substitute and address is wrong, because it may make Excel think that this is a string, not an address. Therefore, it may compare a constant string to the content of the other cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an "[indirect](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)". You're comparing a string address to a cell value.

When you evaluate the formula you basically get this -

[image]

Which evaluated gives you this -

[image]

`If(string<value, true, false)`

You could try an indirect -

```
=IF((INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1",3))<Sheet2!$B$6),1)
```

It will compare the value in the cell to the other cell -

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed the problem I was having

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what the text you're using to `Substitute`, try either of these:

```
=IF((SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","3")<Sheet2!$B$6),true,false)

=IF((SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),1,3)<Sheet2!$B$6),true,false)
```

It may be giving you gruff due to the fact you're looking for a string and replacing with a number.  If not, can you post the text you're using to substitute?